# Correct condition for parsing different json strings iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I'm parsing json for a user authentication system.

If login is successful the server sends following user object;

```
{

    "users": {
        "id": "1",
        "FB_first_name": null,
        "FB_last_name": null,
        "FB_gender": null,
        "FB_id": null,
        "FB_link": null,
        "FB_locale": null,
        "FB_name": null,
        "FB_username": null,
        "created_at": "2011-01-02 08:30:59 UTC",
        "updated_at": "2011-01-02 08:31:23 UTC",
        "email": "admin@8repz.com",
        "language_id": "1"
    }

}
```

which I parse using the following code;

```
    NSDictionary *userDic = (NSDictionary*)[(NSDictionary*)results objectForKey:@"users"];

    User *aUser = [[User alloc] initWithID:[userDic objectForKey:@"id"]
                              withUserName:[userDic objectForKey:@"FB_name"]
                             withUserEmail:[userDic objectForKey:@"email"]
                             withUserFName:[userDic objectForKey:@"FB_first_name"]];
```

But in case of invalid user, the server sends following response;

```
[

    "Invalid Email or Password."

]
```

What `if()` statement should I use to parse and display the response in both conditions?

Comment: you know that's an invalid json, right?

Comment: I validated it at http://jsonlint.com/ before posting the question.

Comment: Roots for JSON can be either a dictionary or an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]){
    //You have to be sure that on error it returns array not a dictionary
    NSArray *arr = (NSArray*)json;
    NSString *errorMsg = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
}
else {

}
```

Comment: I like this result.  It's cleaner than my approach of using nested if statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
//IF RESPONSE IS SIMPLY A STRING OBJECT FOR INVALID STRING, YOU HAVE BAD DATA
if(![results isEqualToString:@"Invalid Email or Password."]){
     if([results objectForKey:@"users"]){  //Check to ensure users object exists
          //You're good 
           NSDictionary *userDic = (NSDictionary*)[(NSDictionary*)results objectForKey:@"users"];

            User *aUser = [[User alloc] initWithID:[userDic objectForKey:@"id"]
                              withUserName:[userDic objectForKey:@"FB_name"]
                             withUserEmail:[userDic objectForKey:@"email"]
                             withUserFName:[userDic objectForKey:@"FB_first_name"]];
     }
}else{
     //Handle error
}
```